# Include API key as a URL query parameter via a Named Credential

Tags: apex, callout, namedcredentials

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setEndpoint('callout:Google/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?');
        req.setHeader('key', '{!$Credential.Password}');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http res = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = res.send(req);
```

Since Google API allowsing us to use ApiKey and we do not need to do Outh2 in that case.

I am using APIKEY in password option in Named Credential.

I have checked Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header option.

- **Error I am getting:**

"error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.

Comment: req.setHeader('key', '{!$Credential.Password}'); this is wrong.
google accepts apikey as the url query param not as an header.
Example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap

Comment: @HR : But when I put {!$Credential.Password} in a query it says 'The URL is invalid'.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you get "The URL is invalid" so we can double check you are merging it in correctly

Comment: @BryanAnderson: Sure. 

I tried passing apikey key using {!$Credential.Password} using below query and it says The URL is invalid. 

req.setEndpoint('callout:Google/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?key={!$Credential.Password});


But when I do 



req.setEndpoint('callout:Google/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?key=abcdxyz); 



where abcdxyz is actual API KEY. This way it isworking fine but I don't want to hardcode ApiKey this way and the reason I want to use Named Credential.

Comment: Is there more of an error message then just  'The URL is invalid'

Comment: @BryanAnderson: Here is the exact error that I am getting : 'System.CalloutException: The URI is invalid.'

Comment: Sorry I just realized I was typing URL but it is URI error

Comment: `HTTPResponse res = httpForAdminUser.send(httpreqCandidate);` you reference this line of code in your original code, but I dont see either variable `httpForAdminUser` or `httpreqCandidate`

Comment: @BryanAnderson: I made those changes in a code of my question. Those variable were just a typo when copy and pasting actual code.

Comment: @DRules I guess we are now seeing two different errors, one that is about Invalid URI, and now another about "You must use an API key to authenticate" which is it

Comment: @identigral: I am looking a way to use named credentials for google api using api key itself in query string or setheader

Comment: @BryanAnderson: I am seeing error: "You must use an API Key to authenticate" when I use apiKey in SetHeader but as per google doc apiKey has to be in a query string. 

So when I use apiKey in query string itself using 'key={!$Credential.Password}' I am seeing 'invalid uri' error. Note: I have saved apiKey in password field of named credentials.

Comment: You may want to try sending your request to https://requestbin.com/ and see what is actually being sent

Comment: @DRules I am having the exact problem, either URI Invalid OR "You must use an API Key to authenticate". Did you find any solution for this?